# CodeIgniter Error on library function call

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to fill options in dropdown by fetching data from database into a view. However I get the error:

Message:  Undefined property: CI_Loader::$AdminDataHelper

Filename: forms/user.php

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_colleges() on a non-object in /ci/app/views/includes/forms/user.php on line 54

```
    <select id="college" name="college-selector" >   
         <?php 
               foreach ($this->AdminDataHelper->get_colleges() as $colleges)
               {
                 echo "<option value='".$colleges['id']."'>".$colleges['description']."</option>";
               }
        ?>                   
     </select>
```

My Library class:-

```
class AdminDataHelper {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('admin_m');      
}

public function get_colleges(){
    return $this->CI->admin_m->get_colleges();
}
```

My model:-

```
class Admin_M extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
    $this->global_db = $this->load->database('global', TRUE); 
}

public function get_colleges()
{
    $this->global_db->select('id, description');
    $this->global_db->from('College');
    $result = $this->global_db->get();
    $data=$result->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

In my autoload.php file I added the library.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'AdminDataHelper');
```

Comment: I think you need to carefully read the docs.  You cannot use a name like that.   Only the first letter of the file name is capitalized and then use all lower-case when referencing it.  `Admindatahelper.php` and then `$this->admindatahelper->`. Follow the examples and see the "naming conventions" section here:  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions

Comment: I also don't think you can call a Library from within a View.  You need to call it from your Controller and only send the data into your View.

Comment: You are right. The issue was with the naming convention. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Carefully read the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions). You cannot use a name like that. Only the first letter of the file name is capitalized and then use all lower-case when referencing it.

Follow the examples and see the "naming conventions" section:

> - File names must be capitalized. For example: `Myclass.php`
> - Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: `class Myclass`
> - Class names and file names must match.

`Admindatahelper.php` and `$this->admindatahelper`

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `Model` in this case instead of using `Library`, however this will work:

```
$this->adminDataHelper->get_colleges();
```

the first character must start with lowercase letter.